# Why is it asking a static lifetime for a local reference?

Tags: rust, reference, static, lifetime

```
pub trait Dinosaur {
    fn roar(&mut self);
}

pub struct Astrodon<'a> {
    data: &'a Vec<usize>,
}

impl<'a> Dinosaur for Astrodon<'a> {
    fn roar(&mut self) {
        println!("Astrodon: {:?}", self.data);
    }
}

pub struct Zoo {
    pub data: Vec<usize>,
    pub dinosaur: Vec<Box<dyn Dinosaur>>,
}

fn main() {
   
    // let data = vec![1,2,3,4,5,6];
    // let mut v: Vec<Box<dyn Dinosaur>> = Vec::new();
    // v.push(Box::new(Astrodon{data: &data}));
    // for d in v.iter_mut()
    // {
    //     d.roar();
    // }
    
    let mut z = Zoo {data: vec![1,2,3,4,5,6], dinosaur: Vec::new()};
    z.dinosaur.push(Box::new(Astrodon{data: &z.data}));
    for d in z.dinosaur.iter_mut() {
        d.roar();
    }
}
```

The code failed to compile due to lifetime issues. Why does it require a static lifetime? Any help will be appreciated!

But if you uncomment out the commented and comment out the rest, it works.

According to this([Forcing the order in which struct fields are dropped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41053542/forcing-the-order-in-which-struct-fields-are-dropped)),  Zoo.data will be dropped before dropping Zoo.dinosaur, so Zoo.dinosaur is pointing to invalid data when dropping, but even I moved Zoo.dinosaur in front of Zoo.data, it still did't work.

Comment: There's a fundamental design problem to solve before looking at lifetimes here. You try to put the zoo in the dinosaurs ? The data structure doesn't seem logical.

Comment: You are creating a struct that references itslef https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct

Comment: Summary of the duplicates: `Box<dyn Dinosaur>` is the reason it requires `'static`, which is what the second linked question says. But even [if you fix that](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=edc7ec7aac2ac5741ec0a6df57e6325f) you just get shunted into a twisty little maze of lifetime errors, all alike, for the reasons explained in the answers to the question lpiepiora linked.