# Actually pinning to the heap using alloc/dealloc in Rust?

Tags: rust, allocation, self-reference, rust-pin

This is something of a follow-up to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76846131/why-doesnt-my-self-referential-struct-work-invalid-memory-reference) of mine. TL;DR: I tried to create a self-referencing struct by heap allocating the self-referencee using a `Box`. It was pointed out that I can't rely on the pointer provenance not changing ([it is currently undecided](https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines/issues/326)).

This led to me trying to implement a sort of custom `Box`, `PinnedClient`, which allocates to the heap when created and deallocates on `Drop`:

```
struct PinnedClient(pub *mut Client);

impl PinnedClient {
    unsafe fn new(client: Client) -> PinnedClient {
        // Allocate memory on the heap
        let layout = Layout::new::<Client>();
        let pointer = alloc(layout) as *mut Client;

        // Make sure it worked
        if pointer.is_null() {
            handle_alloc_error(layout);
        }

        // Move the client object to the heap
        pointer.write(client);

        // Return a `PinnedClient` object with a pointer
        // to the underlying client.
        PinnedClient(pointer)
    }
}

impl Drop for PinnedClient {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        // Deallocate the previously allocated when
        // wrapper is dropped.
        unsafe { 
            dealloc(self.0 as *mut u8, Layout::new::<Client>());
        }
    }
}
```

Then I include a `PinnedClient` in my struct and use the raw pointer to create the self-reference:

```
pub struct MyTransaction<'a> {
    transaction: Transaction<'a>,
    _client: PinnedClient
}

impl<'a> MyTransaction<'a> {
    async fn from_client<'this>(client: Client) -> Result<MyTransaction<'a>, Error> {
        let client = unsafe { PinnedClient::new(client) };
        let transaction = unsafe {
            // Convert `*mut Client` to `&mut Client`
            // This shouldn't fail since the pointer in PinnedCliend
            // is guaranteed not to be null.
            &mut *client.0
        }.transaction().await?;

        Ok(
            MyTransaction { _client: client, transaction }
        )
    }
}
```

Now I am wondering:

- is it undefined behaviour to "hand out" a mutable reference to the `Client` and
- is it it actually guaranteed that the memory gets deallocated (does `dealloc` get called in all scenarios)?

I am somewhat anxious since self-referential structs are supposed to be hard and I feel like I am missing something.

Comment: Note that I didn't say that every time the box is moved its uniqueness is asserted, I said that this _might_ be the case (not decided yet). From a practical point of view, you should approach it as if it was decided positively, to be safe against such future decision.

Comment: This first statement is again wrong: the _address_ of the object won't change. That's a basic fact driven from the fact that `Box` is heap-allocated and it is not allowed to move the memory behind your back. What can change is the _provenance_, what giving you access rights to this place with your reference/pointer.

Answer (score 0):

> is it undefined behaviour to "hand out" a mutable reference to the `Client`

No it is not (of course, assuming you keep all aliasing rules and do not hand out *two* such references).

However, as pointed out in your previous questions, you need to swap the fields, as currently the `Transaction` gets dropped after the `Client` but it may access it during its drop, causing a use-after-free.

> is it it actually guaranteed that the memory gets deallocated (does `dealloc` get called in all scenarios)?

Yes and no.

No, because [in Rust, destructors are not guaranteed to be called](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.forget.html#safety) (barring special requirements of [`Pin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/pin/struct.Pin.html)). If the destructor of `MyTransaction` does not run (because of `std::mem::forget()` or because of a `Rc` cycle or because of whatever), then the memory will not be deallocated.

But also yes, because the answer for the question *you've probably meant to ask* is yes: every time the memory would be deallocated if the pointer was `Box`, is will also be deallocated with your smart pointer. `Box` also uses `Drop`, it is not special (it is special in other ways, though).

However...

You missed it *again*. Your code still leaks resources.

The *backing memory* for the `Client` will be deallocated, but *the `Client` itself* won't be dropped. This means that if your client owns some resources (heap memory, file descriptors, network connections, etc.) they won't be released.

Even if *currently* `Client` doesn't have any drop glue, if it is coming from a library you don't control, nothing promises it will continue to not have drop glue in the future. Adding a `Drop` impl is not considered a breaking change. So you still need to drop it, to be future-proof.

Fortunately, this is easy:

```rust
impl Drop for PinnedClient {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        // Deallocate the previously allocated when
        // wrapper is dropped.
        unsafe { 
            self.0.drop_in_place();
            dealloc(self.0 as *mut u8, Layout::new::<Client>());
        }
    }
}
```

> since self-referential structs are supposed to be hard

You asked two questions here, you failed subtley *twice* to write UB-free code. Is this not hard enough for you?

Comment: Thank you. I just want to remark that I fixed the field order for this question, I actually used `drop_in_place` but excluded it for the example and I didn't say self-referential structs are easy.